# UISplitViewController inside a TabBar with storyboard not changing orientation

Tags: storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I have created a Tab based application with storyboard and in my tab items i add splitview controllers.The problem is as i add splitview controller to tabs, while running application change in interface orientation has no effect. It stays in potrait mode only even though i am returning YES in shouldRotateAutoInterfaceOrientation method.

I am new to story board. Am i doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you return YES in EVERY master and detail view?
If you forgot one, it will not rotate.